# Security related concern for my android phone

Tags: security

i purchased an android  mobile and had my google account set up but the device later went faulty and would not turn on, so now I got the same brand phone exchanged. meanwhile I have also set up my google account to delete itself if at all my faulty phone comes up as the seller took it back. Should I wait before setting up my new phone or will it cause my new phone to not setup properly. How does google's device security detect my account login from a device based on the brand or OS or based on MAC address?.

Comment: You can log off you accounts on other devices from your Google account. Then just change your password.